# PHP Select box removing parent from list

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, uploadify

I have a form to upload images to my website.

The consists on a  box which contains the folders of a directory on my website.

All functions are working but I want it to only display the sub-directories not the parent/sub

here is my current code:

it displays in the form as parent/sub.

```
    {
    <select size="1" name="fileLocation"><?php
    $imFolder = "gallery";
    $dirs = glob($imFolder . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($dirs as $val){
    echo '<option value="'.$val.'">' .$val. "</option>";
    ?></select>
     }
```

Comment: Sorry, you need to remove the "parent" from "parent/sub" output or you need a directory listing?

Comment: OK in the select box at the moment it displays as parent/sub I want it only to display the sub

Comment: Did you try to explode and output the last element of the array given?

Comment: OK I am very new to PHP and TBH struggling a lot, this is my first site moving away from ready made frameworks.  Could you explain what you mean please? sorry for being such a noob!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is get rid of the **parent** in **parent/sub** you can explode it

```
{
    <select size="1" name="fileLocation"><?php
        $imFolder = "gallery";
        $dirs = glob( $imFolder . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR );
        foreach( $dirs as $val ) {

            # explode the value on "/" and get array of variables
            $val = explode( '/', $val );

            # get last value of the given array
            $last_value = sizeof( $val ) - 1;
            $val = $val[ $last_value ];

            echo '<option value="' . $val . '">' . $val . "</option>";
        }
        ?></select>
 }
```

There probably is a cleaner solution, but this should work

Comment: You are welcome. But as I said, keep an eye on this post, there probably is a faster and cleaner solution.